# java pixel image processing

Tags: java, android, image-processing

Java application for Android. There is the following piece of xml:

```
<TableRow>
    <ImageView
            android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
            android: layout_margin = "10dp"
            android: src = "@ drawable / icon_security" />
    <TextView
            android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
            android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
            style = "@ style / DesignerTextStyle2"
            android: layout_gravity = "center_vertical"
            android: text = "@ string / welcome_security_calls" />
</ TableRow>
```

I need to compare pixel image processing of the certain image on the screen (e.g. it is third image on the screen) with the famous image (i.e. this image - "@ drawable / icon_security").

Can you show me an example for solving this problem?

Comment: Are you looking to compare images using pixel values?

Comment: Comparing equality or similarity? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Comparing absolute equality

Answer (score 2):

This is the `Java` code that I use to compare two images using pixel values from `URL`

```
package imager;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
public class Imagecompare
{
    public static void main(String args[])
      {
        String s1;
        BufferedImage img1 = null;
        BufferedImage img2 = null;
        try {
          URL url1 = new URL("http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/Resources/ImageSimilarity/d02.jpg");
          URL url2 = new URL("http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/Resources/ImageSimilarity/s02.jpg");
          img1 = ImageIO.read(url1);
          img2 = ImageIO.read(url2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int width1 = img1.getWidth(null);
        int width2 = img2.getWidth(null);
        int height1 = img1.getHeight(null);
        int height2 = img2.getHeight(null);
        if ((width1 != width2) || (height1 != height2)) {
          System.err.println("Error: Images dimensions mismatch");
          System.exit(1);
        }
        long diff = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height1; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < width1; x++) {
            int rgb1 = img1.getRGB(x, y);
            int rgb2 = img2.getRGB(x, y);
            int r1 = (rgb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g1 = (rgb1 >>  8) & 0xff;
            int b1 = (rgb1      ) & 0xff;
            int r2 = (rgb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
            int g2 = (rgb2 >>  8) & 0xff;
            int b2 = (rgb2      ) & 0xff;
            diff += Math.abs(r1 - r2);
            diff += Math.abs(g1 - g2);
            diff += Math.abs(b1 - b2);
          }
        }
        double n = width1 * height1 * 3;
        double p = diff / n / 255.0;
        double percnt = 100.0-(p*100.0);
        System.out.println("PERCENT: " +percnt);
      }

}
```